# How to use icmptx?

Tags: icmp, tunnel

In Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04, both sides) I want to create an ICMP tunnel. I don't know how to set IP's. I searched and read some documents like [this](http://thomer.com/icmptx) and [this](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-evading-authentication-proxy-using-icmptx-0150347) but I couldn't figure out what exactly I should do and in what server.

1. Is real IP (internet IP) of the client important?
2. Should I enter a virtual IP like 10.0.0.1?
3. Assuming real IP of server is 37.38.39.40, what IP's should I enter in server/client sides?
4. For example I need to know what I should enter as IP in `icmptx -s <ip>` and what in `icmptx -c <ip>`?
5. Should I run `icmptx -s` in 37.38.39.40 and `icmptx -c` in client?

Answer (score 1):

ICMP refers to internet control messaging protocol, the basis of which resolves and ping target in its layer to a particular IP of the server you are trying to reach.

`icmptx -s <server-ip>` refers to your internet accessible IP address of whatever server you can ping.

`icmptx -c <client-ip>` uses the internet or online (public IP) which is given the exact moment you join the network. You can get this from Linux terminal using `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO` - 
this is user or client IP.

Once tunnel has been established you route traffic through your WiFi IP to your external IP, by first deleting the originally placed IP from your router's network address translation and add a newhost using the originally retrieved public IP and routers as gw (gateway).